# HTML5: How to create some white spaces between 2 words by element

Tags: html

I want to display a sentence with some white spaces between two words:

```
"Hello                       
      welcome"
```

-like this,

I don't want to use with pre tag.

is there such a tag for it?

Comment: No tag, just use CSS: Add `white-space: pre` to the element holding the text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&nbsp;`**(Non-breaking space)** to display white spaces without `<pre>` tag.

Try it, it will surely work but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: @NoahShay I am so happy to hear that my answer helped you a bit and can you do me a favour by accepting my answer, it would mean a lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you put in in a span, then use the `white-space: pre;`, you could get what you achieve. See the example:

```css
#whitespace {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This will have normal white-space
  <br><br>
  <span id="whitespace">This will have nowrap white-space            See?</span>
</p>
```

This is the same thing as the `pre` tag, but without the tag.